# Mobile Chrome not Repositioning CSS Background Containers Onload/Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Okay, a little background  -- I wanted to make a single page layout with multiple stacked background images for a home page in drupal and have it easily edited using some div tags in the CMS system.  It seems to be working all well and good in all sorts of different browsers -- even safari *gasp*. Except when I test it on a mobile device.  Chrome on mobile seems to not move my background image positions.  Now it was moving them but I had to cache the window size because when I was scrolling in chrome on mobile it was firing off window resize events every time I scroll (why? I have no idea).

So basically, I can't seem to duplicate this behavior on a desktop.  Any ideas as to why my background containers might not be repositioning themselves correctly to adjust for an increased height of the text container (due to the narrow width).

```
var imageHeight, imageWidth, totalHeight, windowWidth, i;
var imageArray = [];
var textContainerArray  = [];
```

Adjusts window size on load

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    /*Image Containers*/
    imageWidth = window.innerWidth;
    imageHeight = window.innerHeight;
```

Sets initial image locations

```
    textContainerArray[1] = imageHeight*0;
    textContainerArray[2] = imageHeight*1;
    textContainerArray[3] = imageHeight*2;
    textContainerArray[4] = imageHeight*3;  
    i = 1;
    while (i<5){
        imageArray[i] = imageHeight*(i-1);
        console.log(imageArray[i]);
        console.log(i);
        i++
    }   
    i = 1;
```

Determine if there is a container

```
    while (jQuery(".ct-pos-"+i).hasClass("hp-page") == true){
        console.log(jQuery(".ct-pos-"+i).hasClass("hp-page"));

        if (jQuery(".ct-pos-"+i).height() + jQuery(".ct-pos-"+i).offset().top > imageHeight*i){

            if (jQuery(".ct-pos-"+ (parseInt(i) +1)).hasClass("hp-page") == true){
                imageArray[i+1] = jQuery(".ct-pos-"+i).height() + jQuery(".ct-pos-"+i).offset().top;
                textContainerArray[i+1] = (jQuery(".ct-pos-"+i).height() + jQuery(".ct-pos-"+i).offset().top);
            }
        }           
        /*console.log(i);*/
        i++;
    }
```

Sets Position to scale up or scale down until aspect ratio breaks

```
    if (imageWidth*.625 < imageHeight){
        jQuery("#home-bg.bg-1").css('background-position', 'center '+ imageArray[1] + ', center ' + imageArray[2] + 'px, center ' + imageArray[3] + 'px, center ' + imageArray[4] + 'px');
        jQuery("#home-bg.bg-1").css('background-size', 'auto ' + imageHeight +  'px');
        jQuery(".hp-page").css('height', 'auto');

        jQuery(".ct-pos-1").css('top', textContainerArray[1] +  'px');
        jQuery(".ct-pos-2").css('top', textContainerArray[2] +  'px');
        jQuery(".ct-pos-3").css('top', textContainerArray[3] +  'px');
        jQuery(".ct-pos-4").css('top', textContainerArray[4] +  'px');      

        totalHeight = jQuery(".ct-pos-"+4).height() + jQuery(".ct-pos-"+4).offset().top;
        jQuery("#front-page-container").css('height', totalHeight +  'px');
    }
    else if (imageWidth*.625 > imageHeight){
        jQuery("#home-bg.bg-1").css('background-position', 'center 0, center ' + imageWidth*.625 + 'px, center ' + imageWidth*1.25 + 'px, center ' + imageWidth*1.875 + 'px');
        jQuery("#home-bg.bg-1").css('background-size', imageWidth + 'px ' + imageWidth*.625 +  'px');
        jQuery(".hp-page").css('height', 'auto');
        jQuery("#front-page-container").css('height', imageWidth*.625*4 +  'px');
        jQuery(".ct-pos-1").css('top', imageWidth*.625*0 +  'px');
        jQuery(".ct-pos-2").css('top', imageWidth*.625*1 +  'px');
        jQuery(".ct-pos-3").css('top', imageWidth*.625*2 +  'px');
        jQuery(".ct-pos-4").css('top', imageWidth*.625*3 +  'px');

        }
    else if (imageWidth <  768){
        jQuery("a.logo>img").css("display","none");
    }
    else if (imageWidth >  768){
        jQuery("a.logo>img").css("display","inline-block");
    }

});
```

Cache window size and test against resize function  to fire off

```
    windowWidth = jQuery(window).width();

    jQuery(window).resize(function(){
        if (jQuery(window).width() != windowWidth){

            windowWidth = jQuery(window).width();

            imageWidth = window.innerWidth;
            imageHeight= window.innerHeight; 
            /*  sets initial image locations*/
            textContainerArray[1] = imageHeight*0;
            textContainerArray[2] = imageHeight*1;
            textContainerArray[3] = imageHeight*2;
            textContainerArray[4] = imageHeight*3;

            i = 1;
            while (i<5){
                imageArray[i] = imageHeight*(i-1);
                console.log(imageArray[i]);
                console.log(i);
                i++
            }   

            i = 1;
```

Determine if there is a container that goes beyond image size

```
            while (jQuery(".ct-pos-"+i).hasClass("hp-page") == true){   

                if (jQuery(".ct-pos-"+i).height() + jQuery(".ct-pos-"+i).offset().top > imageHeight*i){

                    if (jQuery(".ct-pos-"+ (parseInt(i) +1)).hasClass("hp-page") == true){
                        imageArray[i+1] = jQuery(".ct-pos-"+i).height() + jQuery(".ct-pos-"+i).offset().top;
                        textContainerArray[i+1] = (jQuery(".ct-pos-"+i).height() + jQuery(".ct-pos-"+i).offset().top);
                    }
                }           
                /*console.log(i);*/
                i++;
            }

            totalHeight = jQuery(".ct-pos-"+4).height() + jQuery(".ct-pos-"+4).offset().top;    


            if (imageWidth*.625 < imageHeight){
                jQuery("#home-bg.bg-1").css('background-position', 'center '+ imageArray[1] + ', center ' + imageArray[2] + 'px, center ' + imageArray[3] + 'px, center ' + imageArray[4] + 'px');
                jQuery("#home-bg.bg-1").css('background-size', 'auto ' + imageHeight +  'px');
                jQuery(".hp-page").css('height', 'auto');

                jQuery(".ct-pos-1").css('top', textContainerArray[1] +  'px');
                jQuery(".ct-pos-2").css('top', textContainerArray[2] +  'px');
                jQuery(".ct-pos-3").css('top', textContainerArray[3] +  'px');
                jQuery(".ct-pos-4").css('top', textContainerArray[4] +  'px');      

                totalHeight = jQuery(".ct-pos-"+4).height() + jQuery(".ct-pos-"+4).offset().top;
                jQuery("#front-page-container").css('height', totalHeight +  'px');
            }
            else if (imageWidth*.625 > imageHeight){
                jQuery("#home-bg.bg-1").css('background-position', 'center 0, center ' + imageWidth*.625 + 'px, center ' + imageWidth*1.25 + 'px, center ' + imageWidth*1.875 + 'px');
                jQuery("#home-bg.bg-1").css('background-size', imageWidth + 'px ' + imageWidth*.625 +  'px');
                jQuery(".hp-page").css('height', 'auto');
                jQuery("#front-page-container").css('height', imageWidth*.625*4 +  'px');
                jQuery(".ct-pos-1").css('top', imageWidth*.625*0 +  'px');
                jQuery(".ct-pos-2").css('top', imageWidth*.625*1 +  'px');
                jQuery(".ct-pos-3").css('top', imageWidth*.625*2 +  'px');
                jQuery(".ct-pos-4").css('top', imageWidth*.625*3 +  'px');

            }
            else if (imageWidth <  768){
                jQuery("a.logo>img").css("display","none");
            }
            else if (imageWidth >  768){
                jQuery("a.logo>img").css("display","inline-block");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: That's an awful lot of code for some background images. Can't you just set the background image using background-size: cover?

Comment: No because I can only use 1 div tag for 4 images.   If I used cover I could only have 1 image.